# sklearn preprocessing - ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

Code that is causing error:

```
def preprocess_df(df):
df = df.drop("future", 1) 

for col in df.columns: 
    if col != "target": 
        df[col] = df[col].pct_change()  
        df.dropna(inplace=True)
        print(df[col])
        df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)
```

I felt it was easier to comprehend as an image. (text code + output of print(df[col]) in this pastebin-> https://pastebin.com/we5n4pBS)

[image]

Versions:
Python - 3.8
pip - 21.0.1
scikit-learn(sklearn) - 0.24.1

Comment: And you believe the column does not contain any infinite values?  You're checking the stock volume here.  All it takes is one day where the volume was 0, and you'd end up with an infinite.

Comment: A volume with 0 will cause an infinite value?

Comment: I do see a value of 0, I cant just remove it. How should I deal with it?

Comment: print(max(df[col])) Returns inf.

Comment: There is probably a problem with your data then, since there shouldn't be any infinite price changes.

Comment: Remember how `pct_change` works.  If N is the current value and M is the next one, it computes (M-N)*100/N.  If any entry is 0, that will produce infinity.  And yes, it's quote possible for a stock's volume to be zero on some days.  Percentage change isn't really meaningful for volume.  Maybe you should use a different metric, like absolute difference from day to day.